# CSS webkit filter blur on video, define edges

Tags: javascript, css, filter, blur

I have a full screen video , example: http://jsfiddle.net/z563brct/1/

I am using the `transform:translate` so that the video is always centered in the screen.

The problem comes with the video edges, they are fading as you can see and not strong defined.

How can i mantain all but define or hide the edges?

Comment: Interesting.. It looks like the problem only applies to video and not, say, images. I tried several workarounds (clip-path, negative margins with calc(100% - 12px) width/height...) but none of them seemed to help. I'm betting this has something to do with how the browser handles video surface rendering.

Comment: @thykka maybe the problem is that the video is position:fixed? i also tried scaling the video and put edges uder the window edges but nothing :/

Comment: @sbaaang I also tried with position: absolute; and to place the video within another container. Didn't help at all. I'm guessing the browser only renders the visible area of the video, and anything that gets clipped out is discarded. Thus, when the blur filter attempts to blur the video, the overflowing parts are discarded, causing them to appear white in the filtered result. We'd need an option to repeat edge pixels with the blur filter to prevent this. Have you tried setting a background color to the video element? Although it won't fix the problem, it might make it less visible...

Comment: @thykka yeah looks exactly like the browser takes only visible parts for blur :/